# Why does a string pointer in Objective-C accept and return the value of the string and not a memory address?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

For example in this code:

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
NSLog(@"Greeting message: %@\n", greeting );
```

Greeting takes the value of a string, not an address. It also displays a string in NSLog and not an address. However, I thought pointers were supposed to be used like this:

```
int  var = 20;   /* actual variable declaration */
int  *ip;        /* pointer variable declaration */

ip = &var;  /* store address of var in pointer variable*/

NSLog(@"Address of var variable: %x\n", &var  );

/* address stored in pointer variable */
NSLog(@"Address stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip );

/* access the value using the pointer */
NSLog(@"Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip );

return 0;
```

I've always wondered why it's okay to do this with string pointers.

Comment: Objective-C objects **are not** pointers. They look like a pointer, in many cases they act like a pointer, but they definitely are not pointers in some cases. For example, if you create an NSNumber within a certain range (IIRC, 50 bits of data), or several other types, it isn't a pointer to a memory address at all, instead the object is completely contained inside the pointer itself. Bottom line - don't treat objects as pointers in ObjC, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is something called [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). What we are actually seeing; exactly doesn't happen like that under the hood.

For example, the code you have written:

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
NSLog(@"Greeting message: %@\n", greeting );
```

When you pass `greeting` into NSLog, actually the following line of code gets executed.

```
NSLog(@"Greeting message: %@\n", [greeting description]); // description is a method defined in NSObject and NSString inherits it.
```

And even if you do:

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
```

Now, `greeting` variable doesn't hold the contents of the string, neither it can because it is a pointer. It just holds the address of NSString `@"Hello"` where it is stored. And again, the assignment of pointer happens under the hood. The same is the case with the C language; we can write the following code in C, and it will compile without any errors:

```
char *string = "Hello, world!";
```

In C, the string `"Hello, world!"` is basically a character array, and `string` variable actually stores the pointer to this character array.

If you see the definition of NSLog method, it looks something like this:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

It clearly shows that NSLog message receives an NSString pointer. But what do we actually pass? We pass the NSString in it, but what is **actually** passed is a pointer to that NSString, again under the hood :)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thought as much. But what happens in the assignment statement: `NSString *greeting = @"Hello";` A similar thing? Shouldn't the variable be taking an address value and not a string value?

Comment: `@"Hello"` returns a pointer to the object, not the value. `NSLog` is actually taking *two* pointers in both versions.

Comment: @Fourth: Note that Objective-C objects are *only* managed through pointers, therefore people often use the term "object" when they actually mean "pointer to object" or (in ARC speak) "strong reference to an object".

Comment: @Kitsune Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. It's funny how multiple sites never bother to mention this. Do you by any chance have a citation for it?

Answer (score 1):

`%@` is the string formatter for `NSObject`s, calling the objects [`-description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method. If you want the pointer address of the `string` object try `%p`.

```
NSString *string = @"A string";
NSLog(@"Object contents: %@", string);
NSLog(@"Object address: %p", string);
```